# Deleting a file with an open Handle

Tags: c++, file, winapi

I shouldnt be able to delete a file with an open handle, correct? So i create a file, then i straight away try to delete it, expecting this to fail. Or am i wrong and the handle doesnt have to be closed before deleting the file?

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile (TEXT(file),      
                  GENERIC_WRITE,          
                  0,                      
                  NULL,                   
                  OPEN_ALWAYS,          
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  
                  NULL);                  

if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //FAIL
}

if(DeleteFile(file))
{
    //Should it ever get here cos i dont close the handle?
}
```

Comment: Is this question some OS/library specific ? Then tag accordingly.

Comment: according to docs, handle can be open, will also remain writable, until closed. i believe this is true of all posix-based systems.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the file has been opened.  If the share mode has `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` specified, then it may be deleted by others.

Even if you memory map the file, and it has been opened with this flag (and read/write sharing), then it can still be deleted by the shell (at least I've tried this and it happens, but perhaps the file has simply been renamed and moved to the recycle bin).  In such cases, subsequently accessing the memory will result in an 'InPageError' C-style exception.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would fail.

> The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a
>   file that is open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? MS documentation states that:

> The DeleteFile function fails if an application attempts to delete a file that is open for normal I/O or as a memory-mapped file.

So if you're not getting that behaviour I'd suggest it's down to the way you've opened the file. Are you sure that your check on whether the file is open is completely comprehensive?Have you tried writing to the file first? Can you see the file outside of your own code? (i.e. from Explorer) Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more details.